# Struggling finding clients

Tags: web-development, working-from-home, remote

I'm a freelance programmer, I have started freelancing 2 months ago just after quitting my previous company. I had a good start in the first month, but now I'm struggling to find new clients. I would appreciate any advice or referrals from anyone who needs my skills. I can work with React (Next.js) and Java (JEE) at an intermediate level. You can check out my portfolio here: https://aportfolio.vercel.app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my small town in America we have a city government that has few resources. I met a few people who maintain the city park and discovered they needed a way for an employee at the park to make a reservation and sync it real-time with the employees in the office. I approached them, suggested several ways I could quickly fix it for them, and they agreed to one of them.

Maybe in Madagascar this approach could help you. If opportunities have dried up anyway, there's nothing to lose.

Something like this to a small business or an under-funded non-profit?

> "Hey, I've been coming here for a while and noticed [this problem happening]. I like to help people, I'm a software developer, and right now I have some free time. If I helped you with this problem, would you be a reference for me?"

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should try freelancing sites. Research these sites where you can advertise or look for clients. An example is UpWork. You can network with other programmers or other freelancers you know. They might be able to give you leads. I can also recommend joining Facebook groups that cater to the niche that you have. Also, how about going to local businesses in your city or town. You can make a portfolio and show the owners or managers of these businesses. Since you are a programmer, you have had projects. To connect with potential clients, go to businesses that might need to have a computer program. Upskill, too, so that in case you don't find programming work, you can offer other services. It could be making landing pages. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried to reach local business ( I am from a little town in Madagascar), but they do not even have internet connection and their business do not require too much digital presence, their Facebook page is enough for them. But If you can help, how to get clients on Upwork, I have tried it but no answer...... If someone could find remote job,  that will be very good.

Comment: And of corse, before posting this question I have already searched for clients in many freelancing sites as Upwork, Fiverr,.......   and that's were I found my 1st client

Comment: Freelancing is tough. It doesn't mean that because you got a client, that same client will remain with you for a long time. It's always looking for clients, because the clients just come and go. There's no 100 percent assurance that a good client will not leave.

Answer (score 1):

I found that 'word of mouth' reputation from my first job introduced me to a second customer. This word of mouth reputation seems to get work easier than advertising. You also need to mix with your client base at social functions if possible in your town or area

Comment: Exactly, I confirm.

Answer (score 1):

After long research I found that:One of the best ways to succeed in freelancing is to create something that is really helpful and necessary for daily life for a large number of people. This will not only solve a problem or fulfill a need, but also attract customers who are willing to pay for your solution. A helpful and necessary product or service can also generate positive word-of-mouth and referrals, which can boost your reputation and credibility. Creating something really helpful and necessary for daily life is not easy, but it is worth the effort and investment.